# Can't get ACF field to work with php code

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

this is wordpress ACF code where is my mistake? this code have error in title php code have problem I cant fix it. :(

```
<?php if( get_field('gulet') == 'yes' ) {
echo do_shortcode( '<div class="col-md-12">[slider_recent_items title="<?php the_field('title'); ?>" type="properties" category_ids="" action_ids="" city_ids="" area_ids="" number="" show_featured_only="yes/no"][/slider_recent_items]</div>' );
echo "<style>.slider_container { display: inline-block;} </style>";
} ?>
```

Comment: can you put double quotes instead of single in `the_field('title');` and see if it works?

Comment: also, please try to put "formatted" code so it becomes easy for other people to help you :)

Comment: ´ the_field` returns and echoes - try to use `get_field` instead - also I would maybe format the code like so : `echo do_shortcode( '<div class="col-md-12">[slider_recent_items title="'.get_field("title").'" type="properties" category_ids="" action_ids="" city_ids="" area_ids="" number="" show_featured_only="yes/no"][/slider_recent_items]</div>' );` - This should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, great work